# MongoClient ignores the connection string

Tags: c#, mongodb, timeout, authorization

I just started to use MongoDB(4.4) and its C# driver. I set up my MongoDB with the default option, localhost:27017. Then I turned on the authorization, created a superuser with root permission, like this:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "superuser",
    pwd: "123",
    roles: [ "root" ]
  }
)
```

I tested it on both Mongo shell and Compass, it all worked as expected, connected with correct password, and denied with the wrong one.

Then I created a C# windows form app, use NuGet to install all required packages such as MongoDB.Driver for C#(v2.11.0) and its related packages such as MongoDB.Bson, etc

After that, I used the following code to create a MongoClient:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "mongodb://superuser:12@localhost:27017" );
```

So I expected it should throw an exception because I used the wrong password, "12" in this case. **But it didn't**. Then I tried to list database names with:

```
client.ListDatabaseNames();
```

It threw a timeout exception: "***A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector***"

Even I used the correct password or turned off the authorization, and just go with  "mongodb://localhost:27017" or ""mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017", it still threw the same timeout exception.

It feels like something wrong with that client it created which caused the timeout issue later on. But I couldn't figure out what I am missing.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
The same code works perfectly in a console app, just not a windows form app, which really confuses me.

Comment: For clarity's sake, is your question about why you don't get an exception for an incorrect password until you try and interact with the database? Or is it also not working with the correct password?

Comment: Hi, John, it still doesn't work when I use the correct password, still the same timeout exception. Actually it threw the same timeout exception even I turned off the authorization, and just go with  "mongodb://localhost:27017" or ""mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"

Comment: Are you running your code in a Docker container?

Comment: no, I don't run it in Docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error for 2 days, I finally found a work around for this issue, still don't know why this works though.

So basically I have to split the MongoClient creation and its following function calls separately. I can't do anything related to the MongoClient right after its creation. For example, the following throws the time out exception:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "mongodb://localhost:27017" ); //I turned off authorization
client.ListDatabaseNames();  //Throw time out exception here!!!
```

I have to split them separately in 2 functions call, like one in a "Connect" button event, another one in a "ListDatabaseNames" button event.

Once I did that, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`mongodb://superuser:12@localhost:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1`

because dotNet not support SCRAM-SHA-256 yet

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but it still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: do not put the code inside UI event callback, e.g. Button_Click, Text_Changed. put in main() function.

Comment: Actually that's not the issue, once I split the mongo client creating and its following call into separate functions, then it works. Please see my latest post for detail. Thank you very much for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

Creating a client does not perform any network operations like connecting to your MongoDB deployment - that is done in background. Hence incorrect credentials won't make client creation fail.

`mongo` shell works differently and compass probably performs some queries that would fail if credentials aren't correct.

Why you are getting a timeout error - my guess is it's an ipv4/ipv6 difference. Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. If this doesn't help enable debug information in your driver.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for helping! I tried 127.0.0.1, still not working. I turned off the authorization, and just go with MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" );  still get the timeout exception when I use it to list database names

Comment: You need debugging log output from your driver to troubleshoot.

Comment: I have a typo in the original post, it doesn't have issue in console app, it has issue in windows form app, which is really strange.

Comment: You still need debugging output.